# Php - mysql - Return number of rows

Tags: php, mysql, return, logic, rows

I am trying to get the number of friends that a user has, but I can't seem to get it to work, so i'm really hoping that you can help me.
Here is the php

```
$findFriendssql = "select u.firstName, u.id from friends f, user u 
where (f.u_ID1 = '$loggedId' and u.id = f.u_id2) 
or (f.u_id2 = '$loggedId' and u.id = f.u_id1)";


$all_friends_sql = $db->getRows($findFriendssql);

//$number_of_friends = mysql_num_rows($all_friends_sql);
if ($all_friends_sql) {
$number_of_friends = mysql_num_rows($all_friends_sql);
$friends = "";
foreach ($all_friends_sql as $one_post) {
//doing stuff here.
```

and here is the get rows function

```
public function getRows($sql) {
    $result = array();
    $table = mysql_query($sql, $this->db_link);
    if (!$table) {
        die("\"$sql\" seems to be an invalid query: " . mysql_error());
    }
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($table)) {
        array_push($result, $row);
    }

    return $result;
}
```

whatever I try - I get the error that the num rows expects parameter 1 to be resource.
thank you in advance

Comment: is it throwing any error?

Comment: yah - it throws the expect parameter error, but I can post it for you here.
Warning: mysql_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be resource, array given in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/gamershubFinalLocal/findFriends.php on line 22

Comment: Well, just use **count($all_friends_sql)** in place of  **mysql_num_rows($all_friends_sql)** , though i can't understand your query.

Comment: haha - that worked perfectly  - Thanks anwejunaid! 
my query is to select the firstname of users, which are friends with the logged in person, or a friend of.
If you want - write it as an answer, and i'll accept it.

Comment: You should use `Left join` and `group by` instruction (group on user id) in order to have number on her friend in the same query is better for response performance

Answer (score 0):

```
  $findFriendssql = "select u.firstName, u.id from friends f, user u where (f.u_ID1 = '$loggedId' and u.id = f.u_id2) 
or (f.u_id2 = '$loggedId' and u.id = f.u_id1)";


 $all_friends_sql = $db->getRows($findFriendssql);

 //$number_of_friends = mysql_num_rows($all_friends_sql);
 if (count($all_friends_sql)>0) {
 $number_of_friends = mysqli_num_rows($all_friends_sql);
 $friends = "";
 foreach ($all_friends_sql as $one_post) {
```

Answer (score 0):

The num row is supposed to happen immediatelly after this:

```
$table = mysql_query($sql, $this->db_link);
$totalFirends = mysql_num_rows($table);
```

Use `$table` as input parameter.  `$table` is supposed to be a resource. to be able to use  `mysql_num_rows`.
The following in your function changes `$table` not to be a resource anymore. Besides you do not need this code to know how many friend the user has:

```
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($table)) {
    array_push($result, $row);
    }

    return $result;
}
```

Also if you just need the number then the query should change to `SELECT COUNT(some-field)`

And I do not know what is the content of `$loggedId` hope you tested that the query returns what is supposed to return. is correct the output of the query with a sample data, let say in phpmyadmin?